# Flutter asset not getting loaded in web version with Dart 3

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using an asset image that works as it should in android but it gives the following error in the web-
"The following FormatException was thrown while resolving an image: Message corrupted"

The issue occurs when IDM (Internet Download Manager) intercepts AndroidManifest.bin

[image]

```
• Flutter 3.10.0
• channel stable
• 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
• Dart 3.0.0
```

Answer (score 9):

One temporary solution is to remove your browser from IDM capture list.

This can be done in IDM from Downloads -> Options -> General.

You can follow updates on:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124883

Comment: I've had to downgrade Flutter and not update it for months until I forget what was the reason I did that. Today I upgraded it and got reminded that this is the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Another temporary solution if you don't want to disable idm is that, just hold 'delete' key on your PC (or whatever key you set for idm to tell it to Not intercept links, 'delete' is the default) and refresh the page.

Comment: worked. how to do it programatically?

Comment: i don't think you can, unless you have access to IDM's internal APIs or flutter web changes its internal workings.

in short you have the manifest file as '.bin' in your project and IDM is set to capture those kind of files, as long as you do not remove one of those (or change them) there is no way to change them programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

1. First open your IDM.
2. Downloads -> Options -> General
3. Remove your browser.

Answer (score 0):

first many thanks for telling complete information like `flutter doctor`

I had the same issue before, you should have Condition for web and android,
try it for web and if it worked put your condition:

```
Image.asset(
        'images/my_image.png', // replace with the actual path and name of your image file
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
```

and let me know that I could help you.

happy coding...